# Delete a .lnk file before the program starts MC65 (WM)

Tags: windows-mobile, startup, motorola, autostart

I sit here with an Motorola MC65 and use AppCenter to "lockdown" the device. And the computer works just fine, I install all files I want in the StartUpCtl (OnRestore file) and everything works fine, but when the software updates (through a .cab file) it creates an .lnk file in "Windows\StartUp" and when the device is restarted, this application launches and after this the lockdown mode is activated. This means I cant start the application from the kiosk because is is "already running". I use a command in the OnReset file to remove this .lnk file but when this is done, the program is already started.

How can a remove a .lnk file from the MC65 before it starts?

Comment: acording to this (https://atgsupportcentral.motorolasolutions.com/content/emb/docs/ReleaseNotes/Release%20Notes%20-%20StartUpCtl%20v1.4.htm) StartUpCtl (Motorola software) also supports a DELETE command. Why not use that to delete the lnk file after installation of the cab?

Comment: Yeah Josef, I do this on every reset of the device. StartUpCtl only runs when the device is started, and the program autoruns before StartUpCtl deletes the .lnk file.

Comment: Would be great if I could remove the file through a registry file for example because then it's deleted before the launch.

Comment: You may alter the cab file (see OCP Caab Manger) to not create the lnk - or - use a wait/sleep between the cab setup and the DELETE. There is no registry setting or file that supports deleting a file. Try OCP Windows CE Cab Manager and alter the CAB file, it is an easy one.

Comment: Tnx, will look in to that :)